# How to change the body background-color of all web site pages with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To summarize very shortly, I have a web site http://myWebSite that contains two pages ***page1.html*** and ***page2.html***
I use a CSS style sheet in the head section of page1.html and page2.html

```
<link crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" href="myStyles.css">
```

myStyles.css :

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

On page1.html, I modify the bakground color of the current page with the following JavaScript code :

```
<script>
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="white";
</script>
```

As expected, only the background color of page1.html changes.
How is it possible to keep this modification for all the web site pages ? I suppose I must use cookies. Right ? How can I do that ?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Why are changing it with JS? Why not just change the color in the CSS file? And if you're going to change it in JS, why are you modifying the style sheet itself instead of just `document.body.style.backgroundColor` directly? I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk. It is a brief summary of my problem. I want to create one page to change style of my pages.

Comment: @Stef1611 we understand the issue, and your current solution. But would like to *know* _why_ so, why does the user need this function. _Who_ is this for? It can help shape the answer better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a cookie could work. A slightly better/broader solution would be to use `LocalStorage`. This way, the change would appear in any web browser. There is a good example for using LocalStorage if you are new to this on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

From my code, I have

```
    if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined') {
      if (localStorage) localStorage.setItem('bodyclass', color);
    }
```

and

```
try {
    var bodyClass = localStorage.getItem('bodyclass');
    if (bodyClass) $(document.body).addClass(bodyClass);
  }
catch (e) {
  error.reportError("No local storage support. Changes to body style will not be persistant");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. LocalStorage seems to be a good and slight solution. But If I want to keep this modification when I come to the site, does it work ?

Comment: @Stef1611 It is *possible* to keep your modifications if you use LocalStorage correctly. Note that these modifications will applied only to the computer that they are stored on.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use cookies (cookies are useful for servers, not for browsers). 
Use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to save the current background color locally.

```html
<!-- page1.html -->
<script>
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="white";
localStorage.backgroundColor = "white";
</script>
```

In page2.html you must get the property from localStorage and set the background with it.

```html
<!-- page2.html -->
<script>
var color = localStorage.backgroundColor;
if(color) {
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("style", "color:red; border: 1px solid blue;")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d39brzLk/